# using FOR statement on 2 elements at once python

Tags: python

I have the following list of variables and a mastervariable

`a = (1,5,7)`

`b = (1,3,5)`

`c = (2,2,2)`

`d = (5,2,8)`

`e = (5,5,8)`

`mastervariable = (3,2,5)`

I'm trying to check if 2 elements in each variable exist in the master variable, such that the above would show B (3,5) and D (5,2) as being elements with at least 2 elements matching in the mastervariable. Also note that using sets would result in C showing up as matchign but I don't want to count C cause only 'one' of the elements in C are in mastervariable (i.e. 2 only shows up once in mastervariable not twice)

I currently have the very inefficient:

```
if current_variable[0]==mastervariable[0]:
            if current_variable[1] = mastervariable[1]:
                        True                        
            elif current_variable[2] = mastervariable[1]:
                        True       

  #### I don't use OR here because I need to know which variables match.

elif current_variable[1] == mastervariable[0]:   ##<-- I'm now checking 2nd element
            etc. etc.
```

I then continue to iterate like the above by checking each one at a time which is extremely inefficient. I did the above because using a FOR statement resulted in me checking the first element twice which was incorrect:

```
For i in a:
      for j in a:
           ### this checked if 1 was in the master variable and not 1,5 or 1,7
```

Is there a way to use 2 FOR statement that allows me to check 2 elements in a list at once while skipping any element that has been used already? Alternatively, can you suggest an efficient way to do what I'm trying?

Edit: Mastervariable can have duplicates in it.

Comment: Can mastervariable have duplicates?

Comment: @gnibbler yes, mastervariable can have duplicates

Comment: Are you concerned about your method taking a lot of time, or about it taking a lot of code?

Comment: I was concerned about it taking a lot of code because I figured I would eventually need to write similar functions and if you notice, the solution provided has allowed me to test beyond variables of 3 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where matching elements can be duplicated so that `set` breaks, use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as a multiset - the duplicates between `a` and `master` are found by:

```
count_a = Counter(a)
count_master = Counter(master)
count_both = count_a + count_master
dups = Counter({e : min((count_a[e], count_master[e])) for e in count_a if count_both[e] > count_a[e]})
```

The logic is reasonably intuitive: if there's more of an item in the combined count of `a` and `master`, then it is duplicated, and the multiplicity is however many of that item are in whichever of `a` and `master` has less of them.

It gives a Counter of all the duplicates, where the count is their multiplicity. If you want it back as a tuple, you can do `tuple(dups.elements())`:

```
>>> a
(2, 2, 2)
>>> master
(1, 2, 2)
>>> dups = Counter({e : min((count_a[e], count_master[e])) for e in count_a if count_both[e] > count_a[e]})
>>> tuple(dups.elements())
(2, 2)
```

Comment: @Ivc This looks great. Thanks! Thanks everyone as well and sorry for my terrible explanation of my problem

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good job for sets. Edit: sets aren't suitable since mastervariable can contain duplicates. Here is a version using Counters.

```
>>> a = (1,5,7)
>>> 
>>> b = (1,3,5)
>>> 
>>> c = (2,2,2)
>>> 
>>> d = (5,2,8)
>>> 
>>> e = (5,5,8)
>>> D=dict(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e)
>>> 
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mastervariable = (5,5,3)
>>> mvc = Counter(mastervariable)
>>> for k,v in D.items():
...  vc = Counter(v)
...  if sum(min(count, vc[item]) for item, count in mvc.items())==2:
...   print k
... 
b
e
```

Comment: The problem with sets is that they would show variable C as being true but variable C has 2,2,2 and the master variable has 3,2,5 which means 2 elements don't match

Comment: If mastervariable can have duplicates, you may still have a problem with sets.

Comment: There's no need to use `.get` with Counters - `Counter()['a']` -> 0.